# Dismissing Pushed view controller without NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, viewwillappear

I have two view controllers.

VC1 - Displays data in a tableView, selecting one of the cells goes to VC2.
VC2 - Show text fields to edit the data.

Question - After updating the data and going back to VC1, it does not show the updated data in the table.

I did try adding tableView.reloadData() in ViewWIllAppear but the ViewWillAppear method is not called when I dismiss VC2.

//CODE BELOW
VC2 -

```
@IBAction func saveTask(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(true)
    view.endEditing(true)
    if let task = task {
        task.completed = toggleStatus.isOn
    }
}
```

VC1 -

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the item in the collection of your data that selected from table view

Example:

```
// The collection of your data is used to show in table view
var data: [String] = []

// After navigated back to the VC1, you have to update like:
data[you_selected_index] = inputData // From VC2
tableview.reloadData()
```

**UPDATED**

```
class VC1: UIViewController {
    private var selectedIndex: Int?

}
extension VC1: UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        selectedIndex = indexPath.row
        let vc = VC2()
        vc.delegate = self
        present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
// MARK: - InputInfoVCDelegate
extension VC1: VC2Delegate {

    func onInputInfoSuccessUpdated(source: String?) {
        // Updating data here
        guard let index = selectedIndex else { return }
        data[index] = source
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

```
protocol VC2Delegate: class {
    func onInputInfoSuccessUpdated(source: String?)
}
class VC2: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: VC2Delegate?

    @IBAction private func actionTapToBackButton(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.onInputInfoSuccessUpdated(source: inputTextField.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That would mean I need to access the tableView from VC1 in VC2 and reloaded it from there?

Comment: You have to take the data from VC2 (the input text is edited) and update it in the collection of data in VC 1

Comment: I updated more details about the code to understand easily, please check

Comment: is It working for you? If you are not able to apply them, please update your code above, let me check and fix it for you

Comment: That worked out perfectly! I am new to protocols and delegates - thanks for helping out. This pattern solved the problem.